# Unable to escape single quotes in dynamic sql

Tags: sql-server

I am executing a dynamic Sql snippet in SQL Server where the use case goes like this:

Take a Song ID (`SongId`) which is of an alphanumeric format (Eg: `affgb:2c1`)
and extract some metadata from the Songs table from the Id.

In a normal case it would look like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM SongTable
WHERE SongId = 'affgb:2c1'
```

Due to some constraints I am using dynamic SQL which gets the song Id as a varchar type parameter called `@songId`. The query goes like this:

```
DECLARE @querySongFromId NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @querySongFromId = 'SELECT * FROM SongTable WHERE SongId =' + @songId;
EXECUTE sp_executesql @querySongFromId;
```

The above query is failing as I am unable to insert the single quotes before the `@songId`

I tried escaping the single quotes the following way:

```
SET @querySongFromId = 'SELECT * FROM SongTable WHERE SongId = '' ' + @songId + ' '' ';
```

but I get an `"Incorrect syntax near '=' "` error.

Can someone kindly explain how to fix this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

what about doing it this way:

```
DECLARE @querySongFromId NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @songId VARCHAR(100) = 'affgb:2c1'
SET @querySongFromId = 'SELECT * FROM SongTable WHERE SongId = @songId';
EXECUTE sp_executesql @querySongFromId,N'@songId VARCHAR(100)',@songId;
```